# Mocking a dependency whose property is used in tested class constructor

Tags: java, junit, dependency-injection, mockito

I want to test the Helper class but in the constructor of that class, it contains a dependency, whose attribute is called in order to populate the properties.

How is this possible with Mockito? It works if I spy the Dependency class, but I don't believe that is how spies are supposed to be used.

```
class Dependency {
    private ArrayList<String> property;
    ...
}

class Helper {
    private String a1;
    private String a2;

    public Helper(Dependency dependency) {
        a1 = dependency.property.get(1)
        a2 = dependency.property.get(2)
    }

    public int testedMethod() {
        ...
    }
}

class HelperTest {
    @Mock
    public Dependency dependency;

    @InjectMocks
    public Helper helper;

    public void test() {
        ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you refactor?

In that case, either

- Make Dependency an interface and add proper methods to get hold of the String items, or
- Have Helper depend not on Dependency, but on the String items directly

Resorting to "spies" is a code smell, and should be addressed sooner than later.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by mocking the deeper layer and then having the get() call return a mock. This involves creating a getter for the `property` attribute.

```
@Mock
public ArrayList<String> property;

@Mock
public Dependency dependency;

@InjectMocks
public Helper helper;

@Before
public void setup() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(dependency.getProperty()).thenReturn(property);
    when(property.get(0)).thenReturn("value")
    ...
}
```